# Collect dataframes from List of Dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, collections

I have a list of dataframes, and I want to create a new list of dataframes but only extract the dataframes which contains variables from A to C. My problem is if a dataframe contains more than one of these variables it gets duplicated in the new list and I don't know how to stop this... Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my code below...

```
Collection=[]
for i in range(len(db)):
     for col in db[i]:   
        if col.startswith('A') or col.startswith('B') or col.startswith('C'):     
            Collection.append(db[i])
```

Comment: Use a set instead of a list.

Comment: After `collection.append()`, you can add a `break` so it goes back to the outer loop. `DataFrame`s are not hashable so you cannot use a set here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in this way:

```
Collection=[]
for i in range(len(db)):
    if any(col.startswith(x) for x in ["a","b","c"] for col in db[i]):
        Collection.append(db[i])
```